# Is there a way to exclude the the metadata columns result when using sp_prepare

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, metadata, sql-server-2017

Is there a way to exclude the returned metadata columns when calling sp_prepare?

Example:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE Test
AS
-- Prepare query
DECLARE @P1 int;  
EXEC sp_prepare @P1 output,   
    N'@Param int',  
    N'SELECT 1 as int;';

-- Return handle for calling application
SELECT @P1;

-- Unprepare the query
EXEC sp_unprepare @P1;

GO

EXEC Test
```

The following will return two result sets, the first bieng the metadata, and the second being the desired result. Is there a way to exclude the metadata result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On method to avoid returning the result set to the client is by using `INSERT...EXEC` to insert the result set into a table variable or temp table:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE Test
AS
-- Prepare query
DECLARE @P1 int;  
DECLARE @trash TABLE(int int);
INSERT INTO @trash
    EXEC sp_prepare @P1 output,   
        N'@Param int',  
        N'SELECT 1 as int;';

-- Return handle for calling application
SELECT @P1;

-- Unprepare the query
EXEC sp_unprepare @P1;
GO
```